# The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library appcompat_v7.jar'

Tags: android, eclipse, error-handling

I know this question has been asked many times but unfortunately could'nt find any solution. So here it is

```
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\Zain-ul-abdeen\Android\appcompat_v7\bin\appcompat_v7.jar'    OnClick     Build path  Build Path Problem
```

Clean and built my project many times

Comment: what solution have you tried but didn't work?

Comment: Tried cleaning and building project many times

Answer (score 5):

You have to do the next thing: go to **File>Import>Android>Excisting Android code into workspace** click on **next**. Then you have to chose **browse** and go to the place where your **sdk** folder is located. Next you have to select the folders **extras>android>support>v7** then you wil see a folder named **appcompat** you have to select this folder and click **ok** and after that **finish**.

When this folder is imported right click on your current project folder in Eclipse select **properties**. Next click on **android** and you will see an **add** button. When you click on that you will see a library named **android-support-v7-appcompat** select that and hit **ok**. This will do the job. Hope it will help you out.

Comment: I was about to say the same thing :)

Comment: Personally, I prefer to import android-support-v7-appcompat as a jar file, not the best practice though

Comment: Yeah, I got the same problem a while ago and this worked out fine for me. But I think both ways will lead to the same path :)

Comment: After importing I had 3 projects /android-support-v7-appcompat that I recently added , /appcompat_v7 and /OnClick my sample project. I went into /OnClick properties and did what is written but now it is giving 100 errors :D 
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'. styles_base.xml /android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v21 line 168

Comment: Woooh sorry to hear that. Try this out go to project.properties file in your sample project and change target=android-19 to target=android-21

Comment: Thank you, the error messages in Eclipse were about as helpful as a bag of rocks.

Answer (score 2):

Copy the appcompact_v7.jar to missing folder
C:\Users\Zain-ul-abdeen\Android\appcompat_v7\bin\appcompat_v7.jar

1.if you don't have appcompat_v7.jar download at
[Download appcompat_v7.jar](http://en.sourceforge.jp/projects/sfnet_repairslabandroid/downloads/RepairsLab%20Android/appcompat_v7/bin/appcompat_v7.jar/) 
2.And Copy the appcompat_v7.jar to Missing Folder
3.Clean or Refresh your project
4.And there will show you error and hover on error

and Then Fix your Project Set up [image: Fix Project Setup]

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I already reinstalled the adt plug-in :)